# Multiple comparison on subgroups and overall comparison

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons

I am trying to work out is there is any association between occurrence or not of an event in around 500 individuals and their randomised binary grouping (intervention vs placebo). However I also want to see if this holds true when broken down by one of 5 locations in which the individuals were treated.

A chi square test on the entire group shows a significant result. However if I repeat the test on each of the 5 subgroups only one subgroup is significant (<0.05) and all of the others are non-signficant.

Further still I have then corrected for multiple testing by multiplying the p-values by 6 (5 tests for each centre and then 1 test for entire group). This does not affect the subgroups but does affect the overall group which is no longer significant after multiple testing correction. I know this issue is controversial. Had I just stuck with the original hypothesis and performed one chi square test I would be saying it is significant but once I do subgroup testing I am then having to say this is not the case. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The test across the entire group is an [omnibus test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59910/relation-between-omnibus-test-and-multiple-comparison), and does not need to be adjusted for multiple comparisons. So you would be correcting for $m=5$ multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

(1) As @Alexis wrote, you do not need to correct for the global hypothesis.

(2) It is easier to detect an effect *somewhere* than to actually pinpoint where it originates.  It is thus not rare than a global (omnibus) test is rejected, but some or even none of the post-hoc tests are not.

(3) With 5 hypotheses, there is not much power to be gained with different multiplicity control schemes (but do try BH for [FDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) control).
It seems that you have 50 independent observation for each effect estimate. You should have a lot of power for any reasonably sized effect. Maybe you should change your test statistic.