# Difference between one-way ANOVA and all pairwise comparisons with Bonferroni correction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

If you have five groups and you wish to know if there is a significant difference between any of the group means, you would have to do 10 pairwise comparisons to test all possible pairs of means.  You would have to test

```
  Mean for group 1 vs. mean for group 2 
  Mean for group 1 vs. mean for group 3 
  Mean for group 1 vs. mean for group 4 
  Mean for group 1 vs. mean for group 5 
  Mean for group 2 vs. mean for group 3 
  Mean for group 2 vs. mean for group 4 
  Mean for group 2 vs. mean for group 5 
  Mean for group 3 vs. mean for group 4 
  Mean for group 3 vs. mean for group 5 
  Mean for group 4 vs. mean for group 5
```

If you do each of these tests at the alpha = .05 level, you have 5 chances in a hundred of concluding the difference is significant when it is really just due to chance.  If you 10 such tests you have 
           10 times .05 = .50 or 
a 50/50 chance that one will be significant just by chance.  This is an unacceptable error rate. We could use a Bonferroni correction to adjust the significance levels we're hoping to detect such that we won't have a false Type I error being alerted.

Alternatively, we could also use ANOVA to compare all of these groups.

Aside from computational limitations, what advantage does ANOVA have over pairwise Bonferroni corrected t-tests?

Comment: I guess, this answers your question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/do-we-need-a-global-test-before-post-hoc-tests/9753#9753

Comment: There is actually $1-(1-0.05)^{10}\approx 0.40$ chance that at least one will be significant under the null, not $0.5$. But it does not change the rest of your question, +1.

Comment: One hint is that your 10 comparisons are not independent.

Comment: One guess that I can make with that hint is that ANOVA bases it's analysis on a "grand mean" - that may preserve the independence between comparisons. But I'm honestly not quite certain.

Comment: See [Relation between omnibus test and multiple comparison?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59910/17230). Part of the answer is that omnibus tests like ANOVA are more sensitive to many medium-sized deviations from the null than a collection of multiplicity-corrected pairwise tests; conversely ANOVA's less sensitive to a single large effects, or a few quite large effects, when the others are small.